useSearchParams Returning null or undefined in Next.js Component Tests with Vitest
Problem
I'm working on a Next.js project and using Vitest for testing. I need to mock the next/navigation module, specifically useRouter and usePathname, while keeping the original implementation of useSearchParams. However, when I log the return value of useSearchParams, it returns null.
Using mockRestore, importActual does not work.
Here is a simplified version of my component:
'use client'
import { useState } from "react"
import { usePathname, useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"

const LoginStep = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const router = useRouter()
  const sp = useSearchParams()
  console.log(sp) // This logs null

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)
      // Login logic
      router.replace(sp.get("origin") || "/workspace/trading/bot?page=1&filter=all")
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={login}>
      <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>Login</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default LoginStep

Test Setup
I have created a manual mock for next/navigation to mock useRouter and usePathname, but I want to keep useSearchParams as a native function.
// __mocks__/next/navigation.ts
// __mocks__/next/navigation.ts
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { vi } from 'vitest';


const mockedUseRouterReturnValue = {
  push: vi.fn(),
  back: vi.fn(),
  forward: vi.fn(),
  prefetch: vi.fn(),
  refresh: vi.fn(),
  replace: vi.fn()
}

const mockedUseRouter = vi.fn(() => mockedUseRouterReturnValue);

const mockedUsePathname = vi.fn();

export {
  mockedUseRouter as useRouter,
  mockedUsePathname as usePathname,
  useSearchParams
};

export {
  mockedUseRouterReturnValue
}

Here is my testing file:
import { fireEvent, screen, } from "@testing-library/react" 
import { renderWithProviders } from "@/utils/testing-utils/providers"

import LoginStep from "."

import { mockLoginToServiceAction, mockedLoginToService } from "@/__mocks__/actions/auth/login"
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import { vi, describe, it, expect, beforeEach } from "vitest"

vi.mock('next/navigation')

describe('Given the user has entered all fields correctly on /login?origin=/account/exchanges/binance', 
  it('When they click "Login" button', async () => {
    vi.mocked(useSearchParams).mockRestore()
    
    const { container } = renderWithProviders(
      <LoginStep 
        setLoginStep={(value) => {}}
      />
    )

  })
})

